# Get posts from database in two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using a code in which I call posts from a database in two columns. I use different queries for both columns, means I call posts by categories, few categories in column left and rest in column right. Both columns show 10 latest posts. Now I am inserting load more function which will load more posts. I prefer using single load more button beneath both columns rather than putting two load more buttons inside each column. So my problem is this load more button will load more posts when ever clicked until their are no posts, now suppose categories by which I call posts in left column have more posts than categories of right column it will make left column go longer than right column which i don't want. So is their a better way to call posts in two columns rather than calling posts by half of categories in one and rest in other.

the code i am currently using is:

```
        <div id='container'>
        <div id='lhs' class='column' style='width:370px;margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;'>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id where category='cat1' OR category='cat2' OR category='cat3' OR category='cat4' ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 12";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $title = $row['title'];
        $body = $row['body']; 
        $posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
        $full_name = $row['full_name'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $posted = $row['posted'];

       $get_user_info = "SELECT * FROM userss WHERE username='$posted_by'";
       $get_info = mysqli_query($con,$get_user_info);
       $get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);

       $profilephoto_info = $get_row['profile_photo'];
       if ($profilephoto_info == "") {
       $profilephoto_info = "./img/avatar_pic.png";
      }
        else   {
       $profilephoto_info = "./userdata/profile_photos/".$profilephoto_info;
      }


         echo "<div class='db'>
          <h2>$title</h2>
          <p>" . 
  (strlen($row['body'])>500? 
      substr( $row['body'],0,500)."...<a href='blog.php?blogId=" . $row['blogs_id'] . "' style='font-size:16px;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;'>Read more</a>": 
      $row['body']).
  "</p><br /> 
         <img src='$profilephoto_info' height='60'><br />
         By:&nbsp<a href='$posted_by'>$full_name</a>
         <p>$bio</p>
         <p>$posted</p><br /><hr /><br /><br /></div>";
         }
        ?>
        </div>



        <div id='rhs' class='column' style='width:370px;margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;'>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id where category='cat5' OR category='cat6' OR category='cat7' ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $body = $row['body']; 
        $posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
        $full_name = $row['full_name'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $posted = $row['posted'];

        $get_user_info = "SELECT * FROM userss WHERE username='$posted_by'";
        $get_info = mysqli_query($con,$get_user_info);
        $get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);

        $profilephoto_info = $get_row['profile_photo'];
        if ($profilephoto_info == "") {
        $profilephoto_info = "./img/avatar_pic.png";
       }
        else   {
        $profilephoto_info = "./userdata/profile_photos/".$profilephoto_info;
       }


        echo "<div class='db'>
          <h2>$title</h2>
          <p>" . 
  (strlen($row['body'])>500? 
      substr( $row['body'],0,500)."...<a href='blog.php?blogId=" . $row['blogs_id'] . "' style='font-size:16px;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;'>Read more</a>": 
      $row['body']).
  "</p><br /> 
         <img src='$profilephoto_info' height='60'><br />
         By:&nbsp<a href='$posted_by'>$full_name</a>
         <p>$bio</p>
         <p>$posted</p><br /><hr /><br /><br /></div>";
         }
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good approach to repeatative code. You can change your HTML design except too much coding.

```
<div id='container'>
<ul style="width:740px; margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;">
<?php
$query = "SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id where category='cat1' OR category='cat2' OR category='cat3' OR category='cat4' ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 12";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body']; 
$posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
$full_name = $row['full_name'];
$bio = $row['bio'];
$posted = $row['posted'];

$get_user_info = "SELECT * FROM userss WHERE username='$posted_by'";
$get_info = mysqli_query($con,$get_user_info);
$get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);

$profilephoto_info = $get_row['profile_photo'];
if ($profilephoto_info == "") {
$profilephoto_info = "./img/avatar_pic.png";
}
else   {
$profilephoto_info = "./userdata/profile_photos/".$profilephoto_info;
}


 echo "<li style='float:left; width:49%;'>
    <div class='db'>
  <h2>$title</h2>
  <p>" . 
(strlen($row['body'])>500? 
substr( $row['body'],0,500)."...<a href='blog.php?blogId=" . $row['blogs_id'] . "' style='font-size:16px;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;'>Read more</a>": 
$row['body']).
"</p><br /> 
 <img src='$profilephoto_info' height='60'><br />
 By:&nbsp<a href='$posted_by'>$full_name</a>
 <p>$bio</p>
 <p>$posted</p><br /><hr /><br /><br /></div>
 </li>";
 }
?>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Using "li" tag with float left and width 50% make two column layout.
So need not to use "Load more" link two time. Just call it once and append record at last of "ul"

Check this layout. It it works fine than code for load more. Its much easier to load more with this layout.

Comment: thanks your code is great but this isn't real problem, my problem is in above code i used two codes because in first code i am calling `cat1` `cat2` `cat3` `cat4`blogs from db while in second code  i call `cat5` `cat6` `cat7` blogs . by using your style blogs of first column will be repeated in second column. I want a way in which both columns have different blogs, like distinguishing by `blogs_id` but don't know  to write such a code.

Comment: Is this clients requirement to show cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 & cat5 cat6 cat7 in separate columns. If Its not in requirement than in query load blogs from all categories and load more at last to load blogs from all categories.